# erlang memory grow up when c:l file

Tags: memory, erlang

I found a question, but I am not sure this is bug or other, and I don't know how to deal with it.

One time I c:l(test_data) file twice and found that the memory of relation processes were all grow up. 
This is my test.

Os : linux or win

Erlang Version : R19 or R20

Dir:erl_test

File:
test_server.erl,test_statem.erl,test_fsm.erl,test_data.erl,test_server2.erl.

The test_data.erl is big file, 1M.

The opration is：

```
erl -s make all
erl
main:c(1).        %% will make 4 process: fsm , statem, server
observer:start(). %% open observer, see process memory
main:l().         %% will reload test_data.erl
                  %% look 4 processes memory
main:l().         %% reload test_data again 
                  %% look 4 processes memory, become large
```

main.erl and test_server.erl code:

```
%% main.erl
-module(main).
-export([c/1, l/0]).

%% make process
c(N) ->
    test_fsm:create_mon(N),
    test_statem:create_mon(N),
    test_server:create_mon(N),
    test_server2:create_mon(N),
    ok.

%% reload test_data
l()->
    c:l(test_data).

%% test_server.erl, test_fsm, test_statem's code the same as test_server
-module(test_server).
-behaviour(gen_server).
%% API
-export([start_link/0, create_mon/1]).
%% gen_server callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).
-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).
-record(state, {mon = undefined}).

create_mon(0) -> ok;
create_mon(N) -> 
    start_link(),
    create_mon(N-1).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start(?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    erlang:send_after(10000, self(), init),
    {ok, #state{mon = test_data:get(1)}}.

...

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    Mon = test_data:get(1),
    erlang:send_after(10000, self(), info),
    {noreply, State#state{mon = Mon}}.

...

%%test_data.erl
-module(test_data).
-export([get/1]).
-include("test.hrl").

get(1) ->
     #mon{id = 1,name = "test", kind = 10,boss = 0,type = 0,career = 0,color 
           = 1,auto = 0,icon = 5010011,icon_scale = 1,icon_effect = 
           "",icon_texture = 0,weapon_id = 5010011,foot_icon = 0,desc = 
           "",lv = 1,hp_lim = 1000,att = 0,def = 0,hit = 0,dodge = 0,crit = 
           0,ten = 0,wreck = 0,resist = 0,special_attr = [],resum = 
           [],striking_distance = 0,tracing_distance = 0,warning_range = 
           0,hate_range = 0,speed = 0,skill = [{1110000003,1}],retime = 
           0,att_time = 0,att_type = 0,drop = 0,exp = 100,out = 
           0,collect_time = 0,collect_count = 0,is_fight_back = 
           0,is_be_atted = 1,is_be_clicked = 1,is_armor = 0,del_hp_each_time 
           = [10,10],figure_visible = 1,is_hide_hp = 0,is_hit_ac = 
           0,exp_share_type = 0,anger = 0};
...
get(10000) ->
    ...
....
```

The image is the observer result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkhla.png)

Comment: Please show some description of what you have tried. What do you mean with 'hot' ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your process is holding references to objects in the constant pool for the test_data module. This takes almost no memory, since the references are basically just pointers. When the old version of the module is purged, the constant pool goes away with it, so the test server can't just hold a reference anymore; it needs to have a copy of the data in its own heap.

See this discussion [on the mailing list](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2017-October/093988.html):

> All literals belong to a loaded module instance. When that (old) module 
>   instance is purged, all process heaps are scanned and heaps containing 
>   those literals will do a special garbage collection where the literals 
>   are copied.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. But if I have 1000 processes like this,
   when module instance is purged, memory just like 'leak'.
   If I don't trigger major gc, memory not change.
   Why the process literals woundn't gc automatically?
   Have any good idea to make it solve?

Comment: Generally, processes GC when they need memory. If your processes don't allocate memory often, then they won't GC often either. As a solution you can trigger a GC directly in the process (on a timer, or when you get a message, etc.), or use gen_server's hibernation feature.